# Trying to hook to MessageBeep system API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, api-hook

I've been asked by a client to solve the following pesky issue. They have a custom software that has a tendency of displaying message boxes "left and right" without any apparent reason. For instance, the software itself is an accounting program, and when they take a customer's payment, the message box may be displayed about 3 or 4 times in a row. Each message box plays Windows default sound. Unfortunately the way this software was programmed, the type of sounds it plays is completely wrong. For instance, it may display a warning message box and play the warning system sound when the message itself is just an information. All this is quite annoying for the staff who uses the software.

I tried to contact the vendor who distributes the software, but I hit a deadend with them. So now I am looking for ways to mitigate this issue.

My easiest solution was to suggest to mute the speakers, but unfortunately, they require sound to be present to be able to hear incoming emails, and most importantly, be able to play voice mail from them later. So my solution was to somehow mute message box sounds just for a single process.

From my experience, I know that there're two APIs that may be producing these sounds: [MessageBeep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680356%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and an older [Beep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I also found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks) that explains how to use AppInit_DLLs to hook to system APIs. It works great, except that both of the APIs that I need to hook to come from User32.dll and not from kernel32.dll like the author suggests.

There's also [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks?msg=4342850#xx4342850xx) in the questions section that kinda gives approximate steps to hooking to an API from User32.dll, but when I tried to implement them, there's not enough information (for my knowledge to do it.)

So my questions is, does anyone know how to hook to an API in the User32.dll module?

**EDIT**: PS. Forgot to mention. This software is installed on Windows 7 Professional, with UAC disabled -- because it is not compatible with UAC :)

Comment: It looks like the API you are looking for should really be MessageBoxA/MessageBoxW - these are also responsible for the beep sounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the hard way of doing it: if your app is supposed to be running as Administrator on a pre-Vista Windows, you could get the address of the API via `::GetProcAddress()`, give yourself privileges to write to its memory page, and overwrite the beginning of the API's code with a "`jmp`" assembly instruction jumping into the address of your override function. Make sure your overwrite function takes the same arguments and is declared as `__cdecl`.

Expanded answer follows.

The "standard" technique for API hooking involves the following steps:

### 1: Inject your DLL into the target process

This is usually accomplished by first allocating memory in the target process for a string containing the name/path of your DLL (e.g. "MyHook.dll"), and then creating a remote thread in the target process whose entry point is `kernel32::LoadLibraryA()` passing the name of your DLL as argument. [This page](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87240-windows-api-hooking-injecting-a-dll/) has an implementation of this technique. You'll have to wrestle a bit with privileges, but it's guaranteed to work 100% on Windows XP and earlier OSes. I'm not sure about Vista and post-Vista, *Address Space Layout Randomization* might make this tricky.

### 2. Hook the API

Once your DLL is loaded into the target process, its `DllMain()` will be executed automatically, giving you a chance to run anything you want in the target process. From within your `DllMain`, use `::LoadLibraryA()` to get the `HMODULE` of the library containing the API you want to hook (e.g. "user32.dll") and pass it to `::GetProcAddress()` together with the name of the API you want to hook (e.g. "MessageBeep") to get the address of the API itself. Eventaully give yourself privileges to write to that address' page, and overwrite the beginning of the API with a `jmp` instruction jumping into your detour (i.e. into your "version" of the API to hook). Note that your detour needs to have the same signature and calling convention (usually `_cdecl`) as the API you want to hook, or else monsters will be awakened.

As described here, this technique is somewhat destructive: you can't call back into the original API from the detour, as the original API has been modified to jump into yours and you'll end up with a very tight and nice infinite loop. There are many different techniques that would allow you to preserve and/or call back into the original API, one of which is hooking the `...A()` versions of the API and then calling into the `...W()` versions (most if not all of the `...A()` Windows API's convert ASCII strings into UNICODE strings and end up calling into their `...W()` counterparts).

Comment: No. Sorry. I forgot to mention. It runs on Windows 7, although with UAC disabled.

Comment: I stopped hacking with these things at Windows XP :-( There's a great chance though it still works on Windows 7 as long as UAC is disabled.

Comment: I see. You know after reading about Mhooks: http://codefromthe70s.org/mhook22.aspx I think that's exactly what's done in that code project sample I quoted. The issue is where to call that GetProcAddress() from? It seems to work for an API from kernel32.dll or ntdll.dll but not for any other module...

Comment: `GetProcAddress()` takes an `HMODULE` of the library your API is in. You can get your `HMODULE` through `LoadLibrary("user32")`.

Comment: Well, to call that I need to inject my code into the process for that software, right, since each DLL is loading per process, if I'm not mistaking?

Comment: Yes, and in fact there's a version of that hooking code that also allocates the string "user32.dll" into the target process' memory and then invokes `LoadLibrary` passing that address. Let me see if I can dig it up.

Comment: That would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: There you go - this is the "standard" technique with RemoteThread: http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/87240-windows-api-hooking-injecting-a-dll/

Comment: Thanks. That is very close to what I need. Let me explore it a little bit more.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can patch you application. Find calls to `MessageBeep` and overwrite them with `nop`.

Comment: Yup, this is another valid alternative: statically modifying the executable, with some luck can even change the values of the parameters of the calls, for example from EXCLAMATION to ERROR.

Comment: @Sergius: This will work only if the exe is not signed, which is rarely the case. So I think the alternative that you suggested in that article on CodeProject is the best way to go. I just wish you expanded it for other dlls. BTW, do you have any plans like that in the future?

Comment: @ahmd0: I am not sure whether you really need a signature for your exe. Also you can resign it if your company has a certificate.

Comment: @ahmd0: By the way I have answered your comment on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/49319/Easy-way-to-set-up-global-API-hooks?msg=4586015#xx4586015xx

Comment: @Sergius: Thanks. I didn't see that. For some reason when I tried to hook to `MessageBeep` from the DllMain of the AppInit_DLL using `GetModuleHandle("user32.dll")` it hooked OK but my hook was never called. I tested it with my own exe specifically written to call `MessageBeep`. I then tried to hook to LoadLibraryX functions like you previously suggested, and that one didn't work either. I can upload the source for the whole project if you want to take a look and maybe correct it?

Comment: @ahmd0: Ok, let me take a look at it.

Comment: @Sergius: Here you go: http://sdrv.ms/19A93xQ I basically modified your project off the CodeProject. It is a VS 2008 C++ solution. Most of my code is in the `CFuncs` class in Funcs.cpp and Funcs.h files.

Answer (score 0):

No need to spend time on a custom program to do this.

You can mute a particular application when it's running, and that setting will be remembered the next time you open the application. See https://superuser.com/questions/37281/how-to-disable-sound-of-certain-applications.

There's also the Windows Sound Sentry that will turn off most system sounds, although I'm not aware of any per-application settings for Sound Sentry.

Comment: Thanks. I know that I can mute all system sounds with the Windows mixer, but how do you do this per application?

Comment: @ahmd0: As the linked solution says, you click on the sound icon, open the mixer, and mute the application in question. I don't know how to do it from code. Probably some registry setting or other.

Comment: An application won't show in the mixer window if it's not using it. As I was trying to say, the app in question doesn't use it either. All it relies on is MessageBox API that plays the system sound for it, so it won't show in the mixer window.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Deviare API hook](http://www.nektra.com/products/deviare-api-hook-windows/) and solve the hook in a couple of C# lines. Or you can use EasyHook that is a bit more difficult and less stable.

Comment: This is a C++ question. Also do I have to buy a license to use that library?

Comment: It also works on C++ and you can use it with a NON-COMMERCIAL notice when your code instances it.